Minimum Calculation using table formula ignoring empty cells emacs org mode
Suppose I have the following table:
| Headline     | Time | Effort |   Pay |
|--------------+------+--------+-------|
| *Total time* |*1:16*|        |       |
|--------------+------+--------+-------|
| Some Tasks   | 1:16 |        |       |
| \_  Task one | 1:16 |   2:00 |       |

I would like to write a table formula that calculates $2 * 30 and $3 * 30 and choses the minimum value of the two. However if the cell in $3 is empty, it should ignore it and just return $2 * 30
Here is what I have come up with so far:
#+TBLFM: $4=(min $2 * 30, if($3 == "" || $3 == 0, "", $3 * 30));Et

However this returns the following table with the unecessary 0.00. It should be 38.00 in those cells as well:
| Headline     | Time | Effort |   Pay |
|--------------+------+--------+-------|
| *Total time* |*1:16*|        |  0.00 |
|--------------+------+--------+-------|
| Some Tasks   | 1:16 |        |  0.00 |
| \_  Task one | 1:16 |   2:00 | 38.00 |


What makes you think it should be 38.00? Column 3 is empty so the value it contributes is 0.00; column 2 on that row contributes some value, but the minuimum of the two values is 0, so that's the result of the formula. Maybe you can describe what you wan to get and somebody can suggest a fix for the formula.

Maybe what you want is #+TBLFM: $4 = if ($3 == 0, $2*30, min($2*30, $3*30));t.

@NickD yep that's what I was looking for, my oversight that's what a lack of sleep does

[Make comment into an answer]
The OP has confirmed that what he wanted to do was:
#+TBLFM: $4 = if ($3 == 0, $2*30, min($2*30, $3*30));t

